# opencv - confusion over functions "FindHomography" and "cvFindHomography"

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I am a bit new to opencv. It seems that there are two functions "FindHomography" and "cvFindHomography" that perform exactly the same functionality. So I am quite confused over the difference between them.

Links to documentation are provided:
[FindHomography](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html), [cvFindHomography](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)

Thanks for the any help or clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in this case is that [FindHomography](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography) belongs to the Python interface of OpenCV, and [cvFindHomography](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography) belongs to the C interface.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that both will work fine in a C++ program. If I am going to stick with C++ to use opencv, should I use cvFindHomography over FindHomography?

Comment: There is also the `FindHomography` method in the C++ interface as you pointed out, which is called as `cv::FindHomography(...)`. My advice to you is don't mix the C interface with the C++ interface of OpenCV. Choose one, and stick with it in your application.